# Highlight SQL syntax in a single YAML file on IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, syntax, syntax-highlighting

I have a file named `queries.yaml` in `src/main/resources/` where I have a list of queries, but sometimes it's really hard to read.

Is it possible to highlight the syntax somehow?

Comment: IntelliJ often lets you "inject language or reference" into strings (see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-language-injections.html), is that an option in YAML?

Comment: Yes it is and works as expected! Thanks!